# How do I get the correct 4bytes?

Tags: keccak

I'm using this tool to get the keccak 256 hash:
https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/keccak_256.html

However I'm trying to the 4bytes for executeOrder.

The executeOrder function signature is this:

```
function executeOrder(BaseOrderUtils.ExecuteOrderParams memory params) external
```

The ExecuteOrderParams struct looks like the following:

```
    struct ExecuteOrderParams {
        ExecuteOrderParamsContracts contracts;
        bytes32 key;
        Order.Props order;
        Market.Props[] swapPathMarkets;
        uint256[] minOracleBlockNumbers;
        uint256[] maxOracleBlockNumbers;
        Market.Props market;
        address keeper;
        uint256 startingGas;
        Order.SecondaryOrderType secondaryOrderType;
    }
```

How do I get the right 4bytes from keccak_256?  What do I pass in?

Answer (score 1):

By `4bytes` for `executeOrder`, you might be referring to the bytes corresponding to its function selector.

You can get the same, by using **solidity** (i.e., by adding a function within the same contract) as well as by using library like `ethers.js` in **javascript**.

Using Solidity:

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.24;

contract Market {
    struct Props { 
        address marketToken; 
        address indexToken; 
        address longToken; 
        address shortToken; 
    }
}

contract YourContract {

    // Define the ExecuteOrderParams struct
    struct ExecuteOrderParams {
        // Define struct properties here
        string stringParam;
        uint256 uintParam;
        Market.Props market;
        Market.Props[] swapPathMarkets;
    }
    
    // Function to execute order
    function executeOrder(ExecuteOrderParams memory params) external {
        // Implementation of the executeOrder function
    }
    
    // Function to get function signature bytes for executeOrder
    function getExecuteOrderSignature() external pure returns (bytes4) {
        return this.executeOrder.selector;
    }
}
```

Using Javascript:

```js
const { ethers } = require("ethers");

// ABI of the contract containing the executeOrder() function
const abi = [ { "inputs": [ { "components": [ { "internalType": "string", "name": "stringParam", "type": "string" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "uintParam", "type": "uint256" }, { "components": [ { "internalType": "address", "name": "marketToken", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "address", "name": "indexToken", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "address", "name": "longToken", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "address", "name": "shortToken", "type": "address" } ], "internalType": "struct Market.Props", "name": "market", "type": "tuple" }, { "components": [ { "internalType": "address", "name": "marketToken", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "address", "name": "indexToken", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "address", "name": "longToken", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "address", "name": "shortToken", "type": "address" } ], "internalType": "struct Market.Props[]", "name": "swapPathMarkets", "type": "tuple[]" } ], "internalType": "struct YourContract.ExecuteOrderParams", "name": "params", "type": "tuple" } ], "name": "executeOrder", "outputs": [], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [], "name": "getExecuteOrderSignature", "outputs": [ { "internalType": "bytes4", "name": "", "type": "bytes4" } ], "stateMutability": "pure", "type": "function" } ]

// Create an instance of the Contract interface
const iface = new ethers.utils.Interface(abi);

// Get the function selector for the executeOrder function
const executeOrderSelector = iface.getSighash("executeOrder");

console.log(executeOrderSelector);
```

**P.S.**, You can modify the properties of the struct `ExecuteOrderParams` as per your use-case. Also, use the contract's ABI accordingly.

Comment: How would you pass in a struct?  Like Market.Props?

```
    struct Props {
        address marketToken;
        address indexToken;
        address longToken;
        address shortToken;
    }
```

Comment: @caker, I've modified the answer to accommodate the change that you've mentioned, as well as adjusted the JS code to make it easier to obtain the signature hash using the contract's ABI.

Answer (score 0):

In Solidity you can do:

```
import "contract.sol";

function getSelector() public view returns (bytes4) {
    return contract.executeOrder.selector;
}
```